# undefined method `disallow_value' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x0000000a4b3a98>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, shoulda

I have the following Rspec statement:

```
it "requires a valid email address" do
  should disallow_value("@email.com", "email.com", "my@email",
    "my@e_mail.com", "my!@email.com", "my @email.com").for(:email)
end
```

When I run my tests, this statement always fails with:

```
Failure/Error: should disallow_value("@email.com", "email.com", "my@email",
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `disallow_value' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x000000090ea4a8>
```

My Shoulda versions are:

```
shoulda (3.5.0)
shoulda-context (1.1.6)
shoulda-matchers (2.4.0)
```

Any idea what's going wrong?

UPDATE:

Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is interesting. The [README file was rewritten](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/commit/b8cc03eea1367e40aadd96929d7ef71c3f2df691) in November 2013 to include documentation for `disallow_value`, but despite a [`DisallowValueMatcher` module](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/disallow_value_matcher.rb) devoted to implementing such a matcher, the [spec for it](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/8130adf61e5e04940b83f953e88ccd5fdcfd9210/spec/shoulda/matchers/active_model/disallow_value_matcher_spec.rb) doesn't include any use of the `disallow_value` method. I submitted an [issue against the shoulda-matchers gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/409)

Pending more information on this, I'd recommend using `should_not allow_value` as an alternative.

**Update**: This has been acknowledged as an error in the documentation by the shoulda gem maintainers.

Comment: I've added the relevant portion of my gemfile to the question. Looks like it's setup properly. Any other ideas?

Comment: It's in both the :development and :test group. I defined them jointly.

Comment: Thanks, Peter! You've really gone above and beyond here.

Comment: Thank _you_ for pointing this out. You undoubtedly saved others considerable grief.

Comment: Why was the decision made to remove it? It seems like a useful way to express the statement, and potentially clearer in some cases.